# How not to repeat a statement that is repeating in my method in C#?

Tags: c#, inline, func

I hate to repeat this line at the below function:

```
public void Print()
{
   verticalPosition += bodyFontHeight;
   PrintData(something);

   verticalPosition += bodyFontHeight;
   PrintData(something else);

   verticalPosition += bodyFontHeight;
   PrintData(something else else);
}
```

I thought to write a `inline function` as in `C/C++` and my first attempt was a `Func` delegate.

But unfortunately `Func` does not allow using `ref` or `out` parameters.

Any ideas what should be done in this case ?

Comment: How about using a [for loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx)?

Comment: @Yuriy: oops. my bad. overthought something very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your things in any collection you want

```
things = {something,something else, something else else};
```

and then, just loop over it

```
public void Print()
{
   foreach (thing in things){
      verticalPosition += bodyFontHeight;
      PrintData(thing);
   }
}
```